# Does core data batch faulting preserve ordering?

Tags: core-data

I have some objects which I need to sort in a way that I can't express with sort descriptors (it involves position in a tree).  At the moment I'm sorting them a background thread, collecting their objectIDs, and then returning them to the main context like so:

```
for (NSManagedObjectID *objectID in objectIDs)
{
    NSManagedObject *managedObject = [mainContext existingObjectWithID:objectID error:outError];
    if (!managedObject) return nil;
    [array addObject:managedObject];
}
```

This involves a lot of DB hits, so I'd prefer to do it in one go.  The [Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdPerformance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003468-SW3) recommends doing so using a predicate like this:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:[MyEntity entityName]];
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF IN %@", objectIDs];
NSArray *array = [mainContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

However, I'm worried that I'll lose the ordering, because elsewhere they use a `@"SELF IN %@"` and provide sort descriptors.  Does core data batch faulting preserve ordering?

Comment: Sort descriptors are not mentioned anywhere on that page, nor are they in the sample code you included.

Comment: I did say *elsewhere*. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdImporting.html

Comment: So are you wondering if the fetch request return the objects in the order they were written into the database? Newer versions of core data (I believe it's iOS 5+ and OSX 10.7+) allow for ordered core data models. That should extract the objects that match your predicate in the order they were inserted into the database.

Comment: I'm wondering if it returns objects in the order they were written into the *query*.  Regarding ordered core data models, I think you mean ordered relationships, which isn't relevant here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fetch request with the predicate

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF IN %@", objectIDs]
```

does *not* return the objects in the same order as the object IDs are stored in the array. I made a small test:

```
NSLog(@"%@", objectIDs);
// "0x102005370 <x-coredata://FA77144F-F37B-455C-AC6F-18563A34C4A7/Question/p5>",
// "0x102003700 <x-coredata://FA77144F-F37B-455C-AC6F-18563A34C4A7/Question/p4>",
// "0x1020036f0 <x-coredata://FA77144F-F37B-455C-AC6F-18563A34C4A7/Question/p1>"

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Question"];
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF IN %@", objectIDs];
NSArray *array = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
NSLog(@"%@", array);
// "<Question: 0x10201ae10> (entity: Question; id: 0x1020036f0 <x-coredata://FA77144F-F37B-455C-AC6F-18563A34C4A7/Question/p1> ; data: <fault>)",
// "<Question: 0x10201afe0> (entity: Question; id: 0x102003700 <x-coredata://FA77144F-F37B-455C-AC6F-18563A34C4A7/Question/p4> ; data: <fault>)",
// "<Question: 0x10201b060> (entity: Question; id: 0x102005370 <x-coredata://FA77144F-F37B-455C-AC6F-18563A34C4A7/Question/p5> ; data: <fault>)"
```

By setting the launch argument "-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 3", it can be seen that the fetch request is translated to the SQLite query

```
SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZTEXT, t0.ZTITLE FROM ZQUESTION t0 WHERE  t0.Z_PK IN  (5,4,1)
```

which applies the test `t0.Z_PK IN  (5,4,1)` to all rows in the table. So the order of the objects in the array of the fetch request has no influence on the order of the returned objects.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be super-duper sure, I would just create an 'index' attribute and have it added to the entities when you load them into that array. That way you can simply set the sort descriptor to 'index' and be guaranteed that it'll work.

Comment: Where would the index attribute go?  If it's transient, it won't move into the new context; if it's saved to the store, then there's no guarantee that it won't be overwritten by another thread sorting an overlapping set of objects.

Additionally, I don't want to set a sort descriptor at all - I'm trying to do the sorting in the background; sorting again in the foreground would defeat the purpose.

Comment: It wouldn't be transient. As you insert new entities into the core data store, one of the attributes you would set would be the index. I understand that you are trying to do a complicated sort, but the NSManagedObjects have to come out of the fetch request in SOME order, so you might as well sort them. Your executeFetchRequest method call returns an array, which is sorted, so why not utilize a sort descriptor?

Comment: OK, so then we have the problem that it's no longer threadsafe. The sort order isn't fixed, it depends on options at the start of the sort.  If two sorts are happening together, then one will overwrite the index set by the other, and so one process will end up getting the wrong results.

Comment: ah, I didn't realize you were trying to perform multiple writes on different background threads. I saw that you were using a bg thread, but I thought all core data operations were occurring on one bg thread, not multiples. Concurrency and core data can be very tricky. Although, I haven't been swimming in the deep end of that pool myself. I'm sure you have the Apple Doc's but here's the link anyways: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003385-SW1