# Manipulate Relationships in Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, relationship, nsmanagedobject

I have a NSManagedObject subclass defined like this:

```
extension Item {
  @NSManaged var name: String
  @NSManaged var parent: Item
  @NSManaged var children: [Item]
}
```

In order to set the 'parent' attribute, I use this:

```
anItem.parent = aParent
```

And I know it will automatically append anItem to aParent.children too.

However, I would like the child item to be added at a specific position.
This idea is to have a sorted array of children.

I know I could simply do this:

```
aParent.childen.insert(anItem, atIndex: specificPosition)
```

But is there any method to override or operator to overload in order to automatically achieve that ?

Comment: Shouldn't to-many relationships use NSSet or NSOrderedSet instead of an array?

Comment: It seems you can replace NSOrderedSet with Array in the subclass. It works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inserting the child at a particular position will not ensure the same sort order later when you fetch. 
You will need an additional attribute to define the sort order during the fetch.

Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15556055/529243)

Comment: right, 
PS: probably could give it another attribute to the Object, or you have to figure out a way when you try to query(execute) it.

Comment: Yes, you're right. So I wonder, when will it make sense to define a to-many relationship as ordered ? Knowing that it will be ordered in the fetch.

Answer (score 1):

A couple misconceptions here:

1. CoreData to-many relationships are not of type `Array`, they are `Set` or `NSSet`. This can be verified by having your subclass generated by Xcode.
2. It is possible to to have an ordered relationship - just take a look at the relationship inspector in your Core Data Model. This will change it to a `NSOrderedSet`
3. MAJOR CAVEAT to (2) - The order is determined exclusively by the order that you add them - see [this link](http://nshipster.com/nsorderedset/) for more info.
4. It is much more memory intensive to store these as ordered, if you can, have an attribute you can use to order them after fetching.